# Using PHP to pull data from MySQL table column randomly

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following (assume I already plan to change these to mysqli at a later date and am aware of the insecurity of the queries used), to pull text strings from rows in one column in a MySQL table and the output in a browser would, ideally, be a randomly selected string from this column:

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password); 
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error ()); 

$query="SELECT * FROM `tablename` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
$rows[] = $row;
 }
mysql_close();
$max = count($rows) - 1;
```

Using the following echo line to achieve the last bit  in the browser:

```
echo $rows[rand(0, $max)][0] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][1] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][2] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][3] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][4]$
?>
```

I receive the error "PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in script.php on line 19" in reference to this echo line (which, admittedly, was pieced together from other threads and tutorials, so I do not follow completely), however, I've since resolved all other errors logged and observed, so if possible, how can I amend this so the output is just a single row (the text within it) from the column?

Comment: Are you doing random, twice here?

Comment: var_dump() is your friend - look at what you are trying to access. Undefined offset:0 means that there is nothing in array[0].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faster and better than using RAND()

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password, $database);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

$total_rows = 20; //Generate Random number. You could get $total_rows with a first query counting all rows.
$selected_row = mt_rand(0, $total_rows);
//$selected_row -= 1; //just in case you randomized 1 - $total_rows and still need first row.

//Use the result in your limit.
$query="SELECT * FROM `tablename` LIMIT $selected_row, 1;";
$result=$conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row["columnname"];
}
```

Edit it from `mysql` to `mysqli` (on the fly). You would not want to use `RAND()` if your table is very large. *Believe me!*

Comment: I almost want to -1 for using `mysql_` functions. Please fix this.

Comment: I just based on this: he said, ***assume I already plan to change these to mysqli at a later date and am aware of the insecurity of the queries used),*** . I'd fix that in an edit

Comment: It is for future visitors.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I've just updated to mysqli Object oriented. See if you could spot anything. Doing it on the fly, itchy eyes. I thought it was wise to stick to the OP's request to migrate later to mysqli. There is great advantage having this in mysqli over mysql

Comment: Thank you for the detail: I am able to pull only the first item in the column, so everything appears to be working, however, I cannot seem to get those subsequent row-items as a part of a randomly selected output.

Comment: Did you provide value for $total_rows? try echoing out the random value line to see what you get. Let me know if you get any errors. I've added $total_rows = 20; in my answer. Other than that, limit would get incomplete values.

Comment: Thank you for your most recent edit; that seems to have done it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. any time. I just discovered joining stackoverflow would give me the possibilities of helping people. I like the fun. Being providing answers for less than a week so far, like the building reputation too. Thanks for the appreciation.

Comment: Also, there is no need to loop over the results if you're limiting it to a single result.

Comment: True but this loop would only happen once. That won't have any side effect as I see.

Answer (score 1):

In your `SELECT`-statement, you are telling the database to order the strings randomly. So just get the first one and echo it:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)

echo $row['name_of_field_you_want_to_echo'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You never define the variable $rs. Other than that...

If you are selecting the first items from a SQL query, you don't need to specify both the limit and top.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablename` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Since that will ever return one row, you can use mysql_fetch_row

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

and then you can get the field from that row with

```
echo $row["column_name"];
```

Comment: But just as everyone else is saying, still don't use RAND().